# Configuring Endpoints for Remote Server

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service that is hosted in a Windows Service, which is running on a remote computer. 
My Service and it's clients both work perfectly when working locally on my own machine, but now that I have moved the Service to another machine, the clients cannot consume it. 

Forgive me if this is a silly question (I'm pretty sure it is - but I really need answers!) , but do I need to change the endpoint addresses for the clients?

There are tonnes of resources out there, but none seem to relate to my set up. 
A more general question, which I can't seem to find any beginner friendly resources for - **What things in my code do I need to change, once moving from local to production?** 


*WCF Service Host*

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/DSCentralServiceLibrary/Service1/");

DSCentralServiceLibrary.Service1 contentServer = new DSCentralServiceLibrary.Service1();

                //initialise the servicehost
                centralSvrHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(DSCentralServiceLibrary.Service1), baseAddress);

                //add bindings

                BasicHttpBinding basicBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
                basicBinding.Name = "DSCentralSvr";
                basicBinding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
                basicBinding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom;
                basicBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10067108864;
                basicBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
                basicBinding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
                basicBinding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
                basicBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);


                centralSvrHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
                    typeof(DSCentralServiceLibrary.IService1), 
                    basicBinding, 
                    baseAddress
                );
```

Comment: please show your .config

Comment: My endpoints are configured programmatically. I will edit question to show.

Comment: The code already shown might work. Please show your client config.

Comment: Your client config needs to have the address as http://servername:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/DSCentralServiceLibrary/Service1/ where servername is the machine on which the WCF is hosted

Comment: @Rajesh thanks! so servername needs to be the IP address of the machine?

Comment: No, not necessarily the IP. Use the actual server name, not `localhost`.

Comment: It can be your servername or IP address. Just that the client can identify your server on the network.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you need to change the [endpoints in your client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731745(v=vs.110).aspx), how else can they know what to contact?

WRT your second question:

> What things in my code do I need to change, once moving from local to
>   production?

In your code: nothing. In your .configs: whatever is necessary.

Comment: Well precisely, of course you do. Trouble is, I don't know what I need to change them to.